# How can i get System.Net.Mail.Smtp work on linux enviroment?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, smtpclient, centos8

So, i'm developing an Web API on .NET Core 3.1 that should run on a linux server (CentOS 8) and i need to send transactional e-mails from it.

But the first time i ran the app, when i my API tries to send an e-mail via my company SMTP server it throws an error with not much to say (in my noob view on linux enviroments).

I created an console app to replicate the basiscs of the email sending routine:

```
 class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("myhost.com.br")
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"),
                EnableSsl = false,
                Port = 587
            };

            using var mailMessage = new MailMessage();

            mailMessage.To.Add("my_email@email.com");
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("my_address@email.com", "My nice display name");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Teste";
            mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = "TEST";

            try
            {
                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

That throws this exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090020): GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (C
annot find KDC for realm "username").
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(String package, Boolean isServer, NetworkCredential credential) in /_/src/Common/src/System/
Net/Security/NegotiateStreamPal.Unix.cs:line 510
   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.Initialize(Boolean isServer, String package, NetworkCredential credential, String spn, ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, Ch
annelBinding channelBinding) in /_/src/Common/src/System/Net/NTAuthentication.Common.cs:line 125
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpNegotiateAuthenticationModule.Authenticate(String challenge, NetworkCredential credential, Object sessionCookie, String spn, ChannelBind
ing channelBindingToken) in /_/src/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpNegotiateAuthenticationModule.cs:line 34
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.SetContextAndTryAuthenticate(ISmtpAuthenticationModule module, NetworkCredential credential, ContextAwareResult context) in /
_/src/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpConnection.cs:line 341
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.Authenticate() in /_/src/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpConnection.cs:line 753
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.SendEHelloCallback(IAsyncResult result) in /_/src/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpConn
ection.cs:line 633
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception source) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/ExceptionServices/Exce
ptionDispatchInfo.cs:line 69
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.ConnectAndHandshakeAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) in /_/src/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpConnection.cs:line 
424
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.EndGetConnection(IAsyncResult result) in /_/src/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpTransport.cs:line 177
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result) in /_/src/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpClient.cs:line 986
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at asdsadasd.Program.Main(String[] args) in /tmp/asdsadasd/Program.cs:line 32
   at asdsadasd.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

The same code runs fine on windows enviroment.

Here is me dotnet --info:

```
SDK do .NET Core (refletindo qualquer global.json):
 Version:   3.1.107
 Commit:    617a3e03f4

Ambiente de runtime:
 OS Name:     centos
 OS Version:  8
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         centos.8-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.107/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.7
  Commit:  fcfdef8d6b

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.107 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.7 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.7 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

This server already have permitions to send e-mails via the SMTP server.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "This server already have permitions" mean? Servers don't have permissions, user accounts do. Have you been able to send email from this server by some other method? if so, what was it? Your code seems to be attempting to do Windows / NT Authentication from a Linux server, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: P.S. SmtpClient is obsolete, even Microsoft recommends not to use it. They recommend MailKit instead. Maybe you'd have more luck using that.

Comment: Does code work on Windows?  di you check your email server webpage for SMTP settings? Not all email server use the same smtp settings so you settings may not be compatible with your email server.

Comment: @ADyson our server don't accept that unknow ip's send emails through it, and the new server ip have to be configured to accept requests. This auth is not windows authentication, its from the smtp account itself, it is used like this on various services and Apps

Comment: @ADyson yes, i made it work with MailKit on a few minutes, just have to do a few workarounds for images because in MailKit it has to have an physical file, unlike Smtp AlternateView i could use only the base64 encoded string and build the solution around this, but not a big deal. I never looked around for Stmp libraries, 'cause i aways used SmtpClient and works just fine. Good to know!

Comment: @jdweng yes. your answer its written on the question.